How to resolve PendingIntent issue with Android SDK 34
In my Nativescript app, I am not directly using PendingIntent object but still I am getting the below error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
Please help me to know what could be the best way to resolve this.
I can see PendingIntent in some libraries inside Node_Modules though.
StackTrace::
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.telerik.localnotifications.NotificationRestoreReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+  that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4903) at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2420) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226) at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313) at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8762) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:604) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067) Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentExceptio: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:408) at android.app.PendingIntent.buildServicePendingIntent (PendingIntent.java:767) at android.app.PendingIntent.getService (PendingIntent.java:729) at com.telerik.localnotifications.Builder.applyTapReceiver (Builder.java:187) at com.telerik.localnotifications.Builder.build (Builder.java:88) at com.telerik.localnotifications.Builder.build (Builder.java:38) at com.telerik.localnotifications.NotificationRestoreReceiver.scheduleNotification (NotificationRestoreReceiver.java:56) at com.telerik.localnotifications.NotificationRestoreReceiver.onReceive (NotificationRestoreReceiver.java:37) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (Ac tivityThread.java:4894)

I can see we are using Intent and not PendingIntent

Could you share some of your code to help us understand what's you wrote

Hi @MuhammadAmmar I have edited the question and pasted the stacktrace. Please note I am not using PendingIntent, it must be internal lib which is using it

Also @MuhammadAmmar I tried to update the @NativeScript/local-notifications lib, it did not solve the issue

@MuhammadAmmar do you see any resolution here?

I see @Rahul it's the library which infact is not update under the targeted sdk 34 version.

The solutions are 1) switch to another library. 2) ask the repo owner to fix this. 3) clone the library in your project and fix the pending intent there
